# Struts2 Require the user to upload a file validation

Tags: java, forms, file, struts2

I am uploading a file to my Server using Struts2 file upload, my question is that how do I specifically tell that the it is a requirement to upload a file? here is my interceptor.

```
<action name="audioupload" class="actions.AudioUploadAction"
        method="execute">
        <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="allowedTypes">text/html</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="validation" />
        <interceptor-ref name="workflow" />
        <result name="input">/UploadAudio.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/UploadSuccess.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

How do I specifically tell that the user is required to upload a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is create a ActionClass-validation.xml and inside that you'll declare it here.

```
<validators>
    <field name="theNameOfTheFileTag">
        <field-validator type="required">
            <message>File is required.</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```